# Mistake in HQL query while creating reports through hibernate projection

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

I had the following query working fine but then i had to convert it to hibernate projection for performance issues.

NamedQuery = `" SELECT o FROM OrderJob o "`

was converted to:-

```
String hqlQuery = "select " 
        + "new JobAuditListVO( o.jobDate, o.jobType, customer.name, job.street, payment.description, p.paid,o.invoice) " 
        + " from OrderJob o   " 
        + " join  o.order ordr "
        + " join ordr.customer customer "
        + " join  o.jobAddress job "
        + " join o.payment p"
        + " join p.paymentReceivedMethod payment";
getEntityManager().createQuery(hqlQuery).getResultList();
```

But the list is returning 0 results. While the name query return 2 results.

Comment: it would be quite helpful if you could include the structure of OrderJob (and possibly JobAuditListVO & Customer) as necessary to check if the queries should actually be syntactictally equivalent...

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer. Both the queries are absolutely equivalent. 
The problem was that i had to use Left Join instead of Simple Join. Because some entities were returning null.

Comment: Pro-tip.. Null values in relationships are often a sign, that your database scheme has a problem mapping your use-case correctly. It should be possible to purge the null values by [normalizing your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)